# Find Max Line Count for Unity UI.Text

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, text

I'm trying to determine the max line count of a `UI.Text` with `VerticalOverflow` set to `truncate` so that the line count can be used later. So far I came up this code which obviously is rather unpractical and perhaps even dangerous:

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns the max visible line count of a UI.Text component. The text's vertical
///     overflow must be set to truncate or this method will return 0.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetMaxLineCount(Text text)
{
    if (text == null || text.verticalOverflow != VerticalWrapMode.Truncate) return 0;
    var textBackup = text.text;
    var lineCount = 0;
    text.text = "";
    while (true)
    {
        text.text += "\n";
        Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
        var nextLineCount = text.cachedTextGenerator.lineCount;
        if (lineCount == nextLineCount) break;
        lineCount = nextLineCount;
    }
    text.text = textBackup;
    return lineCount;
}
```

Is there any better way to (pre)determine the max line count of a UI.Text component (before text is truncated at the bottom)?

Comment: I once tried to make something like this few years ago but gave up. I haven't tried it again but I now think that you also need to take into account the size of the Text's font in your calculation. Please don't ask me how because I don't know but you need to do that. Font size, screen height/width and text length.

Comment: Fumbling with calculations involving font size have proven to be far too imprecise. text.cachedTextGenerator.lineCount is not a bad start but the text needs to be fully populated with lines before it returns the max line count.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Neven for pointing me in the right direction! `TextGenerator` can be used to count the max lines in the background. The advantage is that `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases()` doesn't need to be called anymore and the original Text won't be changed. It still needs a loop to figure out the max lines but it's far better than my first approach ...

```
public static int GetMaxLineCount(Text text)
{
    var textGenerator = new TextGenerator();
    var generationSettings = text.GetGenerationSettings(text.rectTransform.rect.size);
    var lineCount = 0;
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    while (true)
    {
        s.Append("\n");
        textGenerator.Populate(s.ToString(), generationSettings);
        var nextLineCount = textGenerator.lineCount;
        if (lineCount == nextLineCount) break;
        lineCount = nextLineCount;
    }
    return lineCount;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned in comment that "Fumbling with calculations involving font size have proven to be far too imprecise. ", I think if you use TextGenerator it's precise enough and doesn't need to much perfomance. What I was thinking is you calculate height when there is one row  (rowHeight) and when there are two rows (twoRowHeight)
//rowDistance = twoRowHeight-2*rowHeight;
("n" is number of rows)
You can then write n*rowHeight+(n-1)rowDistance <= maxHeight, solve it for n and you get n = Trunc((totalHeight+rowDistance)/(rowHeight+rowDistance));

Comment: I suggest you make an experiment, one calculating the maximum number of rows your original way (since we know this is 100% precise) and then using this method, make a loop that gradually increases maximum height and record all results then compare them to see when the calculation is off. I think you will get pretty good results for this (I read online that Unity internally uses TextGenerator too, but can't guarantee it). If that doesn't work you can expand the precision, calculation height of 3 rows so you can calculate the top-bottom padding.

Comment: I still understand this is not great, but Unity's support on this really sucks, also please do the experiment and post the results here, I think this method is pretty precise and not to mention it has just a fraction of overhead comparing to your original way.

Comment: @NevenIgnjic For my purpose the method above is fine. It only needs to be called if the text area size changes and otherwise it reports the line count reliably. If I have other issues with UI.Text limitations so I will check out of TextMeshPro can help me there. They are going to integrate TMPro into Unity 2018 so that's a promising text support solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this

`TextGenerator textGenenerator = new TextGenerator();
 TextGenerationSettings generationSettings = 
 text.GetGenerationSettings(text.rectTransform.rect.size); 
 float height = textGenenerator.GetPreferredHeight(newText, generationSettings);`

You can read more about it here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextGenerator.html

---Note related to your code---

You call Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases() which would make a lot of calls for updating only one Text and having bad inspector settings when running that code you could end up in infinite loop if Text allows for infinite rows.

Comment: The Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases() is what worries me because it might have a high impact if a lot of UI is rendered. However Text will likely crash before an infinite loop because of the text being too large for the text mesh.